# Syntax Error with Python

Tags: python

I dev tools for automating a spot on a FB game, but since I encounter a problem Syntax that I had not two days ago ... yet I do not see j or 'could have done error.

If anyone sees clearer than me to find out what would actually be great and will help me to continue my project suddenly.

-> This is the line: 422

[Screenshot of Python Idle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev5i5.png)

```
    # File: j (Python 3.4)

import json
import urllib.request as urllib
import urllib.parse as urllib
import http.client as http
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
import time
import hashlib
import sys
dragon_heart = 'xxx'
session_id = 'xxx'
user_id = xxx
realm_number = 1
c = 1
server = 'realm{}.c{}.castle.rykaiju.com'.format(realm_number, c)
cookie = '__utma=54346615.1735014085.1418478784.1420098297.1420260161.37; __utmc=54346615; __utmz=54346615.1420260161.37.36.utmcsr=castle.wonderhill.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/platforms/kabam; __utmt_~49=1; __utmt_~50=1; __utmt_~51=1; __utma=109650694.1096652092.1418485402.1420282135.1420308691.91; __utmb=109650694.6.10.1420308691; __utmc=109650694; __utmz=109650694.1420308691.91.91.utmcsr=castle.wonderhill.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/platforms/kabam; dragons={}'.format(session_id)
version = 'overarch'
stdparams = 'dragon%5Fheart={0}&user%5Fid={1}&version={2}&%5Fsession%5Fid={3}&%5Fmethod=get'.format(dragon_heart, user_id, version, session_id)
realm = 'realm{0}.c{1}.castle.rykaiju.com'.format(realm_number, c)
location = ''
Ttype = ''
speedyn = 0
job_id = 0
operation_list = [
    'player',
    'general',
    'forge']

def clear_screen(header1, subheader1 = ''):
    import os
    if os.name == 'nt':
        pass
    1('clear')
    print('\n' + header1)
    print('\n' + subheader1)
    ul = '=' * 79
    print('\n{0}\n'.format(ul))


def status(operation):
    url = 'http://%s/api/%s.json' % (server, operation)
    i = 0
    success = False
    while success == False:
        if i >= 7:
            print('Something is wrong, please check idle, resources, speeds, queues, and internet connection.  Exiting...')
            time.sleep(3)
            sys.exit(0)
        params = '?' + stdparams + '&timestamp=' + str(int(time.time()))
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url + params)

        try:
            response_json = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf8'))
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            e = None

            try:
                print('Invalid response from server:  Check your realm variables entered.')
                time.sleep(3)
                sys.exit(0)
            finally:
                e = None
                del e

        except KeyError:
            e = None

            try:
                success = False
                time.sleep(2)
            finally:
                e = None
                del e

        except ValueError:
            e = None

            try:
                success = False
                time.sleep(2)
            finally:
                e = None
                del e

        except HTTPError:
            e = None

            try:
                print('Invalid response from server:  Check your realm variables entered.')
                time.sleep(3)
                sys.exit(0)
            finally:
                e = None
                del e



        try:
            success = response_json['result']['success']
            if success == False:

                try:
                    n = 0
                    while n < len(response_json['result']['errors']):
                        print(response_json['result']['errors'][n])
                        n += 1
                except KeyError:
                    e = None

                    try:
                        print('Failed, retrying...')
                    finally:
                        e = None
                        del e

                except ValueError:
                    e = None

                    try:
                        print('Failed, retrying...')
                    finally:
                        e = None
                        del e



            time.sleep(2)
        except KeyError:
            e = None

            try:
                success = False
                time.sleep(2)
            finally:
                e = None
                del e

        except ValueError:
            e = None

            try:
                success = False
                time.sleep(2)
            finally:
                e = None
                del e

        except UnboundLocalError:
            e = None

            try:
                success = False
                time.sleep(2)
            finally:
                e = None
                del e


        if operation in operation_list:
            return response_json
        None += 1
    return response_json

req = status('player')
capital_id = req['cities']['capital']['id']
location = 'spectral'
location = req['cities'][location]['id']
locationcap = capital_id

def myajax(realm, url, params, cookie, method = 'POST'):
    commandstring = 'Draoumculiasis' + params + 'LandCrocodile' + url + 'Bevar-Asp'
    encodedcommandstring = commandstring.encode('utf8')
    shaofencodedcommandstring = hashlib.sha1(encodedcommandstring).hexdigest()
    headers = {
        'Host': realm,
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Content-Length': len(params),
        'Origin': 'http://castlemania-production.s3.amazonaws.com',
        'x-s3-aws': shaofencodedcommandstring,
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
        'DNT': 1,
        'Cookie': cookie }
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(realm, 80)
    conn.request(method, url, params, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()

    try:
        jsondata = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf8'))
    except:
        print(response)
        sys.exit()

    conn.close()
    return jsondata

built = 0
blue_ene = 0
bluecheck = 0
print("Welcome to Fruit Loops' Auto Revive / clone Script")
print(50 * '*')
time.sleep(1)
print('\nThis Script preserves BE Glitch\n===============================')
time.sleep(1)
print('\nTroops available for reviving:\n==============================')
print('1. Arctic Leviathan     2. Battle Dragon  3. Dragon Rider')
print('4. Sand Strider         5. Fire Mirror    6. Giants')
print('7: Pack Dragon          8. Dimensional R. 9. Soul Reaper')
print('10:Fangtooth            11.Granite Ogre   12.Lava Jaw')
print('13:Banshee              14.Frost Giant    15.Petrified Titan')
print('16:Venom Dweller        17.Lightning C.   18.Storm Drake')
print('19.Venge Wyrm')
troop = int(input('\nEnter TROOP you want to Revive(number):'))
print(40 * '=')
print('Coords to attack:\n')
coordx = int(input('Enter X coord(Coo):'))
coordy = int(input('Enter Y coord(Coo):'))
while blue_ene <= 0 or blue_ene % 15 != 0:
    if bluecheck > 1:
        print('You have entered invalied number for BE\n')
        print(39 * '=')
    blue_ene = int(input('\nEnter your Blue Energy Amount:'))
    bluecheck = bluecheck + 1
    if bluecheck == 10:
        print('BE must give round number when divided by 15!! Ex: 6 750 000/15=450 000')
        sys.exit()
        continue
    build = int(input('Enter No. of  BATCHES to do:'))
    print(79 * '=')
    if troop == 1:
        Ttype = 'ArcticLeviathan'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Arctic Leviathan'
        power = 15
    if troop == 2:
        Ttype = 'BattleDragon'
        number = round(blue_ene / 10)
        name = 'Battle Dragon'
        power = 7
    if troop == 3:
        Ttype = 'DragonRider'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Dragon Rider'
        power = 75
    if troop == 4:
        Ttype = 'DesertTroop'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Sand Strider'
        power = 10
    if troop == 5:
        Ttype = 'FireMirror'
        number = round(blue_ene / 10)
        name = 'Fire Mirror'
        power = 10
    if troop == 6:
        Ttype = 'Giant'
        number = round(blue_ene / 10)
        name = Ttype
        power = 9
    if troop == 7:
        Ttype = 'PackDragon'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Pack Dragon'
        power = 6
    if troop == 8:
        Ttype = 'DimensionalRuiner'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Dimensional Ruiner'
        power = 35
    if troop == 9:
        Ttype = 'IceTroop'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Soul Reaper'
        power = 10
    if troop == 10:
        Ttype = 'AquaTroop'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Fangtooth'
        power = 10
    if troop == 11:
        Ttype = 'StoneTroop'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Granite Ogre'
        power = 9
    if troop == 12:
        Ttype = 'FireTroop'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Lava Jaw'
        power = 8
    if troop == 13:
        Ttype = 'WindTroop'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Banshee'
        power = 6
    if troop == 14:
        Ttype = 'FrostGiant'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Frost Giant'
        power = 8
    if troop == 15:
        Ttype = 'ForestTroop'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Petrified Titan'
        power = 20
    if troop == 16:
        Ttype = 'SwampTroop'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Venom Dweller'
        power = 9
    if troop == 17:
        Ttype = 'LightningCannon'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Lightning Cannon'
        power = 10
    if troop == 18:
        Ttype = 'ChargeTroop'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Storm Drake'
        power = 10
    if troop == 19:
        Ttype = 'VengeWyrm'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Venge Wyrm'
        power = 10
    generals = list()
    params = 'dragon%%5Fheart=%s&timestamp=%d&version=overarch&%%5Fsession%%5Fid=%s&user%%5Fid=%d' % (dragon_heart, int(time.time()), session_id, user_id)
    url = 'http://%s/api/cities/%s.json' % (realm, capital_id)
    jsonData = myajax(realm, url, params, cookie)
    for x in range(0, len(jsonData['city']['generals'])):
        generals.insert(x, jsonData['city']['generals'][x]['id'])

general1 = generals[6]
general2 = generals[1]
general3 = generals[2]
print('\nITEMS TO BE USED:')
if not input('\nEnter No. of Dark Testronius Infusions to use: '):
    pass
infu = int(0)
if not input('Enter No. of Dark Testronius Deluxes to use: '):
    pass
deluxe = int(0)
if not input('Enter No. of Jumps (1h) to use: '):
    pass
jump = int(0)
if not input('Enter No. of Leaps (2.5h) to use: '):
    pass
leap = int(0)
if not input('Enter No. of Bounces (8h) to use: '):
    pass
bounce = int(0)
if not input('Enter No. of Bores (15h) to use: '):
    pass
bore = int(0)
if not input('Enter No. of Bolts (24h) to use: '):
    pass
bolt = int(0)
if not input('Enter No. of Blast (2.5d) to use: '):
    pass
blast = int(0)
if not input('Enter No. of Blitzes (4d) to use: '):
    pass
blitz = int(0)
print('\n')
print(79 * '=')
all = jump + leap * 2.5 + bounce * 8 + bore * 15 + bolt * 24 + blast * 60 + blitz * 96
minonumber = number + 250000
input('\nPress ENTER to start...')
header = 'AUTO TRANSFORMING'
clear_screen(header)
start_time = time.time()
for x in range(0, build):
    print('\n')
    print(79 * '=')
    print('\nSending Attack')
    print('==============')
    t = time.time()
    realm = 'realm%d.c%d.castle.rykaiju.com' % (realm_number, c)
    params = 'user%5Fid={0}&dragon%5Fheart={1}&march%5Bx%5D={2}&march%5Bmarch%5Ftype%5D=attack&timestamp={3}&%5Fsession%5Fid={4}&march%5Bgeneral%5Fid%5D={5}&march%5Bunits%5D=%7B%22{6}%22%3A1%2C%22Minotaur%22%3A{7}%7D&%5Fmethod=post&march%5By%5D={8}&version=overarch'.format(user_id, dragon_heart, coordx, int(time.time()), session_id, general1, Ttype, minonumber, coordy)
    url = 'http://realm{}.c{}.castle.rykaiju.com/api/cities/{}/marches.json'.format(realm_number, c, locationcap)
    cadena = 'Draoumculiasis' + params + 'LandCrocodile' + url + 'Bevar-Asp'
    cadenau = cadena.encode('utf8')
    m = hashlib.sha1(cadenau)
    xs3 = m.hexdigest()
    headers = {
        'Host': realm,
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Content-Length': len(params),
        'Origin': 'http://castlemania-production.s3.amazonaws.com',
        'x-s3-aws': xs3,
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
        'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
        'DNT': 1,
        'Cookie': cookie }
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(realm, 80)
    conn.request('POST', url, params, headers)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    responseData = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    items = json.loads(responseData)
    Duration = items['result']['job']['duration']
    print('\nWaiting for attack to hit.')
    time.sleep(Duration)
    print('\nWaiting for Spectral outpost to update')
    time.sleep(15)
    checkup = 0
    while checkup == 0:

        try:
            params = '{0}&%5Fmethod={1}'.format(stdparams, 'put')
            url = 'http://%s/api/cities/%s.json' % (realm, capital_id)
            jsondata = myajax(realm, url, params, cookie)
            checkup = len(jsondata['city']['souls'])
        continue
        continue
        continue

    datat = jsondata['city']['souls'][Ttype]
    datat = int(datat)
    if checkup > 1:
        datam = jsondata['city']['souls']['Minotaur']
        datam = int(datam)
    build1 = int(datat / number)
    datatr = int(datat - build1 * number)
    Ex = 0
    if build1 < 1:
        if datat > 1 * number:
            build1 = 1
        if datat > 2 * number:
            build1 = 2
        if datat > 3 * number:
            build1 = 3

    print('\nAuto Reviving')
    print('=============')
    for kj in range(0, build1):
        while job_id == 0:

            try:
                time.sleep(4)
                realm = 'realm%d.c%d.castle.rykaiju.com' % (realm_number, c)
                params = 'user%5Fid={}&dragon%5Fheart={}&timestamp={}&%5Fsession%5Fid={}&units%5Bunit%5Ftype%5D={}&units%5Bquantity%5D={}&%5Fmethod=post&version=overarch'.format(user_id, dragon_heart, int(time.time()), session_id, Ttype, number)
                url = 'http://realm{0}.c{1}.castle.rykaiju.com/api/cities/{2}/units/resurrect.json'.format(realm_number, c, location)
                cadena = 'Draoumculiasis' + params + 'LandCrocodile' + url + 'Bevar-Asp'
                cadenau = cadena.encode('utf8')
                m = hashlib.sha1(cadenau)
                xs3 = m.hexdigest()
                headers = {
                    'Host': realm,
                    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                    'Content-Length': len(params),
                    'Origin': 'http://castlemania-production.s3.amazonaws.com',
                    'x-s3-aws': xs3,
                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11',
                    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Accept': '*/*',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
                    'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8',
                    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
                    'DNT': 1,
                    'Cookie': cookie }
                conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(realm, 80)
                conn.request('POST', url, params, headers)
                response = conn.getresponse()
                responseData = response.read().decode('utf-8')
                items = json.loads(responseData)
                idValue = items['result']['job']['id']
                job_id = idValue
                runat = items['result']['job']['run_at']
                timestamp = items['timestamp']
            continue
            continue
            continue

        print('\nReviving: ', number, ' ', Ttype, '\n')
        Atestro = 0
        testro = 0
        timeleft = (runat - timestamp) / 3600
        while timeleft > all:
            timeleft = timeleft * 0.7
            Atestro = Atestro + 1
            time.sleep(0.1)
        testro = Atestro - infu * 13 - deluxe * 2
        if testro < 0:
            testro = 0
        objects = [
            {
                'object': 'DarkTestroniusInfusion',
                'quantity': infu },
            {
                'object': 'DarkTestroniusDeluxe',
                'quantity': deluxe },
            {
                'object': 'DarkTestroniusPowder',
                'quantity': testro },
            {
                'object': 'Blitz',
                'quantity': blitz },
            {
                'object': 'Blast',
                'quantity': blast },
            {
                'object': 'Bolt',
                'quantity': bolt },
            {
                'object': 'Bore',
                'quantity': bore },
            {
                'object': 'Bounce',
                'quantity': bounce },
            {
                'object': 'Leap',
                'quantity': leap },
            {
                'object': 'Jump',
                'quantity': jump }]
        time.sleep(5)
        for obj in objects:
            item = obj['object']
            qty = obj['quantity']
            if qty != 0:
                qtyNo = 0
                while qtyNo != qty:

                    try:
                        time.sleep(1)
                        params = '{0}&job%5Fid={1}&timestamp={2}&%5Fmethod={3}'.format(stdparams, job_id, int(time.time()), 'delete')
                        url = 'http://%s/api/player_items/%s.json' % (realm, item)
                        jsondata = myajax(realm, url, params, cookie)
                        result = jsondata['result']['success']
                        print('Using: ', item)
                        qtyNo = qtyNo + 1
                        safety = 'DarkTestroniusPowder'
                        if safety == item:
                            runat = jsondata['result']['item_response']['run_at']
                            timestamp = jsondata['timestamp']
                            timeleft = (runat - timestamp) / 3600
                            if timeleft > all:
                                qtyNo = qtyNo - 1
                            if timeleft < all:
                                qtyNo = qty

                        time.sleep(0.5)
                    continue
                    continue
                    continue

                continue
        time.sleep(2)
        job_id = 0
        built = built + 1
        build1 = 0
        kj = 0

    if checkup > 1:
        time.sleep(3)
        time.sleep(1)
        realm = 'realm%d.c%d.castle.rykaiju.com' % (realm_number, c)
        params = 'user%5Fid={0}&dragon%5Fheart={1}&units%5Bquantity%5D={2}&timestamp={3}&%5Fsession%5Fid={4}&units%5Bunit%5Ftype%5D=Minotaur&%5Fmethod=delete&version=overarch'.format(user_id, dragon_heart, datam, int(time.time()), session_id)
        url = 'http://realm{0}.c{1}.castle.rykaiju.com/api/cities/{2}/units/release.json'.format(realm_number, c, capital_id)
        cadena = 'Draoumculiasis' + params + 'LandCrocodile' + url + 'Bevar-Asp'
        cadenau = cadena.encode('utf8')
        m = hashlib.sha1(cadenau)
        xs3 = m.hexdigest()
        headers = {
            'Host': realm,
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Content-Length': len(params),
            'Origin': 'http://castlemania-production.s3.amazonaws.com',
            'x-s3-aws': xs3,
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11',
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
            'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
            'DNT': 1,
            'Cookie': cookie }
        conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(realm, 80)
        conn.request('POST', url, params, headers)
        print('\nReleasing remaining mino')
    time.sleep(1)
    realm = 'realm%d.c%d.castle.rykaiju.com' % (realm_number, c)
    params = 'user%5Fid={0}&dragon%5Fheart={1}&units%5Bquantity%5D={2}&timestamp={3}&%5Fsession%5Fid={4}&units%5Bunit%5Ftype%5D={5}&%5Fmethod=delete&version=overarch'.format(user_id, dragon_heart, datatr, int(time.time()), session_id, Ttype)
    url = 'http://realm{0}.c{1}.castle.rykaiju.com/api/cities/{2}/units/release.json'.format(realm_number, c, capital_id)
    cadena = 'Draoumculiasis' + params + 'LandCrocodile' + url + 'Bevar-Asp'
    cadenau = cadena.encode('utf8')
    m = hashlib.sha1(cadenau)
    xs3 = m.hexdigest()
    headers = {
        'Host': realm,
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Content-Length': len(params),
        'Origin': 'http://castlemania-production.s3.amazonaws.com',
        'x-s3-aws': xs3,
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
        'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
        'DNT': 1,
        'Cookie': cookie }
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(realm, 80)
    conn.request('POST', url, params, headers)
    print('\nReleasing remaining: ', name)
    print('\nNumber of BATCHES done: ', built)
    print('***********************\nItems used:')
    print('===========')
    if testro != 0:
        print('Dark Testronius Powder: ', testro * built)
    if deluxe != 0:
        print('Dark Testronius Deluxe: ', deluxe * built)
    if infu != 0:
        print('Dark Testronius Infusion: ', infu * built)
    if jump != 0:
        print('Jump: ', jump * built)
    if leap != 0:
        print('Leap: ', leap * built)
    if bounce != 0:
        print('Bounce: ', bounce * built)
    if bore != 0:
        print('Bore: ', bore * built)
    if bolt != 0:
        print('Bolt: ', boltbr)
    if blast != 0:
        print('Blast: ', blast * built)
    if blitz != 0:
        print('Blitz: ', blitz * built)
    if build > 1 and build != built:
        print('\nWaiting for generals...')
        time.sleep(10)
    time.sleep(Duration)

totalpower = number * built * power
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print(79 * '=')
print('\nElapsed time: {0}'.format(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(elapsed_time))))
print('\n\nRevived {0} of {1} in total power of {2}'.format(format(number * built, ',d'), name, format(totalpower, ',d')))
print('\nReviving completed!!\n')
print(79 * '=')
input('Press Enter to Exit...')
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Sincerely,
highboy

Comment: If you use `try` statement it must be followed by `except`

Comment: [Near-duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792491/try-else-except-syntax-error).

Comment: By the way, putting three `continue` statements in a row is not useful. Python won't suddenly compile if you just insist hard enough.

Comment: when you see an error with a code fragment such as your try/except block, experiment with it in a small fragment on the side. If its still puzzling, post the experiment.

Answer (score 1):

when you write a `try` statement in python it must be followed by an `except` statement, if you want the program to do nothing if an error occurs then just add `except:pass` after the try:

```
#code before
try:
   #this might raise an error
except:pass
#keep going with other stuff
```

right near the top of the file you have

```
user_id = xxx
```

which will raise a name error since xxx is being treated as a variable instead of a string like the 3 lines above, I'd highly recommend testing the program more frequently to rule out fairly trivial errors.

Answer (score 0):

I also see a few other issues:

---

```
import urllib.request as urllib
import urllib.parse as urllib
```

the second import overwrites the first, and you have no way to call `urllib.request`.

---

```
1('clear')
```

... really? That's a syntax error; I think you mean `os.system('clear')`, or `os.system('cls')` if `os.system == 'nt'` (not `pass`).

---

`round` isn't really necessary, ie

```
number = round(blue_ene / 15)
```

could just use integer division

```
number = blue_ene // 15     # gives int, assuming blue_ene is int
```

---

The long cascade of `if`s (lines 235 - 329) could be replaced with a decent data structure, ie a dict of integer: TroopType.

Comment: Yes, i have edited all error from Hugh Bothwell (Thanks).

But, already the same problem, error syntax @ line 422.. 

You can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i have edited all error from Hugh Bothwell (Thanks).

But, already the same problem, error syntax @ line 422..

```
    # File: j (Python 3.4)

import json
import urllib.request as urllib
import urllib.parse as urllib
import http.client as http
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
import time
import hashlib
import sys
dragon_heart = 'xxx'
session_id = 'xxx'
user_id = 111
realm_number = 222
c = 333
server = 'realm{}.c{}.castle.rykaiju.com'.format(realm_number, c)
cookie = '__utma=54346615.1735014085.1418478784.1420098297.1420260161.37; __utmc=54346615; __utmz=54346615.1420260161.37.36.utmcsr=castle.wonderhill.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/platforms/kabam; __utmt_~49=1; __utmt_~50=1; __utmt_~51=1; __utma=109650694.1096652092.1418485402.1420282135.1420308691.91; __utmb=109650694.6.10.1420308691; __utmc=109650694; __utmz=109650694.1420308691.91.91.utmcsr=castle.wonderhill.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/platforms/kabam; dragons={}'.format(session_id)
version = 'overarch'
stdparams = 'dragon%5Fheart={0}&user%5Fid={1}&version={2}&%5Fsession%5Fid={3}&%5Fmethod=get'.format(dragon_heart, user_id, version, session_id)
realm = 'realm{0}.c{1}.castle.rykaiju.com'.format(realm_number, c)
location = ''
Ttype = ''
speedyn = 0
job_id = 0
operation_list = [
    'player',
    'general',
    'forge']

def clear_screen(header1, subheader1 = ''):
    import os
    if os.name == 'nt':
        pass
    os.system('clear')
    print('\n' + header1)
    print('\n' + subheader1)
    ul = '=' * 79
    print('\n{0}\n'.format(ul))


def status(operation):
    url = 'http://%s/api/%s.json' % (server, operation)
    i = 0
    success = False
    while success == False:
        if i >= 7:
            print('Something is wrong, please check idle, resources, speeds, queues, and internet connection.  Exiting...')
            time.sleep(3)
            sys.exit(0)
        params = '?' + stdparams + '&timestamp=' + str(int(time.time()))
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url + params)

        try:
            response_json = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf8'))
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            e = None

            try:
                print('Invalid response from server:  Check your realm variables entered.')
                time.sleep(3)
                sys.exit(0)
            finally:
                e = None
                del e

        except KeyError:
            e = None

            try:
                success = False
                time.sleep(2)
            finally:
                e = None
                del e

        except ValueError:
            e = None

            try:
                success = False
                time.sleep(2)
            finally:
                e = None
                del e

        except HTTPError:
            e = None

            try:
                print('Invalid response from server:  Check your realm variables entered.')
                time.sleep(3)
                sys.exit(0)
            finally:
                e = None
                del e



        try:
            success = response_json['result']['success']
            if success == False:

                try:
                    n = 0
                    while n < len(response_json['result']['errors']):
                        print(response_json['result']['errors'][n])
                        n += 1
                except KeyError:
                    e = None

                    try:
                        print('Failed, retrying...')
                    finally:
                        e = None
                        del e

                except ValueError:
                    e = None

                    try:
                        print('Failed, retrying...')
                    finally:
                        e = None
                        del e



            time.sleep(2)
        except KeyError:
            e = None

            try:
                success = False
                time.sleep(2)
            finally:
                e = None
                del e

        except ValueError:
            e = None

            try:
                success = False
                time.sleep(2)
            finally:
                e = None
                del e

        except UnboundLocalError:
            e = None

            try:
                success = False
                time.sleep(2)
            finally:
                e = None
                del e


        if operation in operation_list:
            return response_json
        None += 1
    return response_json

req = status('player')
capital_id = req['cities']['capital']['id']
location = 'spectral'
location = req['cities'][location]['id']
locationcap = capital_id

def myajax(realm, url, params, cookie, method = 'POST'):
    commandstring = 'Draoumculiasis' + params + 'LandCrocodile' + url + 'Bevar-Asp'
    encodedcommandstring = commandstring.encode('utf8')
    shaofencodedcommandstring = hashlib.sha1(encodedcommandstring).hexdigest()
    headers = {
        'Host': realm,
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Content-Length': len(params),
        'Origin': 'http://castlemania-production.s3.amazonaws.com',
        'x-s3-aws': shaofencodedcommandstring,
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
        'DNT': 1,
        'Cookie': cookie }
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(realm, 80)
    conn.request(method, url, params, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()

    try:
        jsondata = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf8'))
    except:
        print(response)
        sys.exit()

    conn.close()
    return jsondata

built = 0
blue_ene = 0
bluecheck = 0
print("Welcome to Fruit Loops' Auto Revive / clone Script")
print(50 * '*')
time.sleep(1)
print('\nThis Script preserves BE Glitch\n===============================')
time.sleep(1)
print('\nTroops available for reviving:\n==============================')
print('1. Arctic Leviathan     2. Battle Dragon  3. Dragon Rider')
print('4. Sand Strider         5. Fire Mirror    6. Giants')
print('7: Pack Dragon          8. Dimensional R. 9. Soul Reaper')
print('10:Fangtooth            11.Granite Ogre   12.Lava Jaw')
print('13:Banshee              14.Frost Giant    15.Petrified Titan')
print('16:Venom Dweller        17.Lightning C.   18.Storm Drake')
print('19.Venge Wyrm')
troop = int(input('\nEnter TROOP you want to Revive(number):'))
print(40 * '=')
print('Coords to attack:\n')
coordx = int(input('Enter X coord(Coo):'))
coordy = int(input('Enter Y coord(Coo):'))
while blue_ene <= 0 or blue_ene % 15 != 0:
    if bluecheck > 1:
        print('You have entered invalied number for BE\n')
        print(39 * '=')
    blue_ene = int(input('\nEnter your Blue Energy Amount:'))
    bluecheck = bluecheck + 1
    if bluecheck == 10:
        print('BE must give round number when divided by 15!! Ex: 6 750 000/15=450 000')
        sys.exit()
        continue
    build = int(input('Enter No. of  BATCHES to do:'))
    print(79 * '=')
    if troop == 1:
        Ttype = 'ArcticLeviathan'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Arctic Leviathan'
        power = 15
    if troop == 2:
        Ttype = 'BattleDragon'
        number = round(blue_ene / 10)
        name = 'Battle Dragon'
        power = 7
    if troop == 3:
        Ttype = 'DragonRider'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Dragon Rider'
        power = 75
    if troop == 4:
        Ttype = 'DesertTroop'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Sand Strider'
        power = 10
    if troop == 5:
        Ttype = 'FireMirror'
        number = round(blue_ene / 10)
        name = 'Fire Mirror'
        power = 10
    if troop == 6:
        Ttype = 'Giant'
        number = round(blue_ene / 10)
        name = Ttype
        power = 9
    if troop == 7:
        Ttype = 'PackDragon'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Pack Dragon'
        power = 6
    if troop == 8:
        Ttype = 'DimensionalRuiner'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Dimensional Ruiner'
        power = 35
    if troop == 9:
        Ttype = 'IceTroop'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Soul Reaper'
        power = 10
    if troop == 10:
        Ttype = 'AquaTroop'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Fangtooth'
        power = 10
    if troop == 11:
        Ttype = 'StoneTroop'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Granite Ogre'
        power = 9
    if troop == 12:
        Ttype = 'FireTroop'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Lava Jaw'
        power = 8
    if troop == 13:
        Ttype = 'WindTroop'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Banshee'
        power = 6
    if troop == 14:
        Ttype = 'FrostGiant'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Frost Giant'
        power = 8
    if troop == 15:
        Ttype = 'ForestTroop'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Petrified Titan'
        power = 20
    if troop == 16:
        Ttype = 'SwampTroop'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Venom Dweller'
        power = 9
    if troop == 17:
        Ttype = 'LightningCannon'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Lightning Cannon'
        power = 10
    if troop == 18:
        Ttype = 'ChargeTroop'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Storm Drake'
        power = 10
    if troop == 19:
        Ttype = 'VengeWyrm'
        number = round(blue_ene / 15)
        name = 'Venge Wyrm'
        power = 10
    generals = list()
    params = 'dragon%%5Fheart=%s&timestamp=%d&version=overarch&%%5Fsession%%5Fid=%s&user%%5Fid=%d' % (dragon_heart, int(time.time()), session_id, user_id)
    url = 'http://%s/api/cities/%s.json' % (realm, capital_id)
    jsonData = myajax(realm, url, params, cookie)
    for x in range(0, len(jsonData['city']['generals'])):
        generals.insert(x, jsonData['city']['generals'][x]['id'])

general1 = generals[6]
general2 = generals[1]
general3 = generals[2]
print('\nITEMS TO BE USED:')
if not input('\nEnter No. of Dark Testronius Infusions to use: '):
    pass
infu = int(0)
if not input('Enter No. of Dark Testronius Deluxes to use: '):
    pass
deluxe = int(0)
if not input('Enter No. of Jumps (1h) to use: '):
    pass
jump = int(0)
if not input('Enter No. of Leaps (2.5h) to use: '):
    pass
leap = int(0)
if not input('Enter No. of Bounces (8h) to use: '):
    pass
bounce = int(0)
if not input('Enter No. of Bores (15h) to use: '):
    pass
bore = int(0)
if not input('Enter No. of Bolts (24h) to use: '):
    pass
bolt = int(0)
if not input('Enter No. of Blast (2.5d) to use: '):
    pass
blast = int(0)
if not input('Enter No. of Blitzes (4d) to use: '):
    pass
blitz = int(0)
print('\n')
print(79 * '=')
all = jump + leap * 2.5 + bounce * 8 + bore * 15 + bolt * 24 + blast * 60 + blitz * 96
minonumber = number + 250000
input('\nPress ENTER to start...')
header = 'AUTO TRANSFORMING'
clear_screen(header)
start_time = time.time()
for x in range(0, build):
    print('\n')
    print(79 * '=')
    print('\nSending Attack')
    print('==============')
    t = time.time()
    realm = 'realm%d.c%d.castle.rykaiju.com' % (realm_number, c)
    params = 'user%5Fid={0}&dragon%5Fheart={1}&march%5Bx%5D={2}&march%5Bmarch%5Ftype%5D=attack&timestamp={3}&%5Fsession%5Fid={4}&march%5Bgeneral%5Fid%5D={5}&march%5Bunits%5D=%7B%22{6}%22%3A1%2C%22Minotaur%22%3A{7}%7D&%5Fmethod=post&march%5By%5D={8}&version=overarch'.format(user_id, dragon_heart, coordx, int(time.time()), session_id, general1, Ttype, minonumber, coordy)
    url = 'http://realm{}.c{}.castle.rykaiju.com/api/cities/{}/marches.json'.format(realm_number, c, locationcap)
    cadena = 'Draoumculiasis' + params + 'LandCrocodile' + url + 'Bevar-Asp'
    cadenau = cadena.encode('utf8')
    m = hashlib.sha1(cadenau)
    xs3 = m.hexdigest()
    headers = {
        'Host': realm,
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Content-Length': len(params),
        'Origin': 'http://castlemania-production.s3.amazonaws.com',
        'x-s3-aws': xs3,
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
        'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
        'DNT': 1,
        'Cookie': cookie }
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(realm, 80)
    conn.request('POST', url, params, headers)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    responseData = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    items = json.loads(responseData)
    Duration = items['result']['job']['duration']
    print('\nWaiting for attack to hit.')
    time.sleep(Duration)
    print('\nWaiting for Spectral outpost to update')
    time.sleep(15)
    checkup = 0
    while checkup == 0:

        try:
            params = '{0}&%5Fmethod={1}'.format(stdparams, 'put')
            url = 'http://%s/api/cities/%s.json' % (realm, capital_id)
            jsondata = myajax(realm, url, params, cookie)
            checkup = len(jsondata['city']['souls'])
        continue

    datat = jsondata['city']['souls'][Ttype]
    datat = int(datat)
    if checkup > 1:
        datam = jsondata['city']['souls']['Minotaur']
        datam = int(datam)
    build1 = int(datat / number)
    datatr = int(datat - build1 * number)
    Ex = 0
    if build1 < 1:
        if datat > 1 * number:
            build1 = 1
        if datat > 2 * number:
            build1 = 2
        if datat > 3 * number:
            build1 = 3

    print('\nAuto Reviving')
    print('=============')
    for kj in range(0, build1):
        while job_id == 0:

            try:
                time.sleep(4)
                realm = 'realm%d.c%d.castle.rykaiju.com' % (realm_number, c)
                params = 'user%5Fid={}&dragon%5Fheart={}&timestamp={}&%5Fsession%5Fid={}&units%5Bunit%5Ftype%5D={}&units%5Bquantity%5D={}&%5Fmethod=post&version=overarch'.format(user_id, dragon_heart, int(time.time()), session_id, Ttype, number)
                url = 'http://realm{0}.c{1}.castle.rykaiju.com/api/cities/{2}/units/resurrect.json'.format(realm_number, c, location)
                cadena = 'Draoumculiasis' + params + 'LandCrocodile' + url + 'Bevar-Asp'
                cadenau = cadena.encode('utf8')
                m = hashlib.sha1(cadenau)
                xs3 = m.hexdigest()
                headers = {
                    'Host': realm,
                    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                    'Content-Length': len(params),
                    'Origin': 'http://castlemania-production.s3.amazonaws.com',
                    'x-s3-aws': xs3,
                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11',
                    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Accept': '*/*',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
                    'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8',
                    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
                    'DNT': 1,
                    'Cookie': cookie }
                conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(realm, 80)
                conn.request('POST', url, params, headers)
                response = conn.getresponse()
                responseData = response.read().decode('utf-8')
                items = json.loads(responseData)
                idValue = items['result']['job']['id']
                job_id = idValue
                runat = items['result']['job']['run_at']
                timestamp = items['timestamp']
            continue
            continue
            continue

        print('\nReviving: ', number, ' ', Ttype, '\n')
        Atestro = 0
        testro = 0
        timeleft = (runat - timestamp) / 3600
        while timeleft > all:
            timeleft = timeleft * 0.7
            Atestro = Atestro + 1
            time.sleep(0.1)
        testro = Atestro - infu * 13 - deluxe * 2
        if testro < 0:
            testro = 0
        objects = [
            {
                'object': 'DarkTestroniusInfusion',
                'quantity': infu },
            {
                'object': 'DarkTestroniusDeluxe',
                'quantity': deluxe },
            {
                'object': 'DarkTestroniusPowder',
                'quantity': testro },
            {
                'object': 'Blitz',
                'quantity': blitz },
            {
                'object': 'Blast',
                'quantity': blast },
            {
                'object': 'Bolt',
                'quantity': bolt },
            {
                'object': 'Bore',
                'quantity': bore },
            {
                'object': 'Bounce',
                'quantity': bounce },
            {
                'object': 'Leap',
                'quantity': leap },
            {
                'object': 'Jump',
                'quantity': jump }]
        time.sleep(5)
        for obj in objects:
            item = obj['object']
            qty = obj['quantity']
            if qty != 0:
                qtyNo = 0
                while qtyNo != qty:

                    try:
                        time.sleep(1)
                        params = '{0}&job%5Fid={1}&timestamp={2}&%5Fmethod={3}'.format(stdparams, job_id, int(time.time()), 'delete')
                        url = 'http://%s/api/player_items/%s.json' % (realm, item)
                        jsondata = myajax(realm, url, params, cookie)
                        result = jsondata['result']['success']
                        print('Using: ', item)
                        qtyNo = qtyNo + 1
                        safety = 'DarkTestroniusPowder'
                        if safety == item:
                            runat = jsondata['result']['item_response']['run_at']
                            timestamp = jsondata['timestamp']
                            timeleft = (runat - timestamp) / 3600
                            if timeleft > all:
                                qtyNo = qtyNo - 1
                            if timeleft < all:
                                qtyNo = qty

                        time.sleep(0.5)
                    continue
                    continue
                    continue

                continue
        time.sleep(2)
        job_id = 0
        built = built + 1
        build1 = 0
        kj = 0

    if checkup > 1:
        time.sleep(3)
        time.sleep(1)
        realm = 'realm%d.c%d.castle.rykaiju.com' % (realm_number, c)
        params = 'user%5Fid={0}&dragon%5Fheart={1}&units%5Bquantity%5D={2}&timestamp={3}&%5Fsession%5Fid={4}&units%5Bunit%5Ftype%5D=Minotaur&%5Fmethod=delete&version=overarch'.format(user_id, dragon_heart, datam, int(time.time()), session_id)
        url = 'http://realm{0}.c{1}.castle.rykaiju.com/api/cities/{2}/units/release.json'.format(realm_number, c, capital_id)
        cadena = 'Draoumculiasis' + params + 'LandCrocodile' + url + 'Bevar-Asp'
        cadenau = cadena.encode('utf8')
        m = hashlib.sha1(cadenau)
        xs3 = m.hexdigest()
        headers = {
            'Host': realm,
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Content-Length': len(params),
            'Origin': 'http://castlemania-production.s3.amazonaws.com',
            'x-s3-aws': xs3,
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11',
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
            'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
            'DNT': 1,
            'Cookie': cookie }
        conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(realm, 80)
        conn.request('POST', url, params, headers)
        print('\nReleasing remaining mino')
    time.sleep(1)
    realm = 'realm%d.c%d.castle.rykaiju.com' % (realm_number, c)
    params = 'user%5Fid={0}&dragon%5Fheart={1}&units%5Bquantity%5D={2}&timestamp={3}&%5Fsession%5Fid={4}&units%5Bunit%5Ftype%5D={5}&%5Fmethod=delete&version=overarch'.format(user_id, dragon_heart, datatr, int(time.time()), session_id, Ttype)
    url = 'http://realm{0}.c{1}.castle.rykaiju.com/api/cities/{2}/units/release.json'.format(realm_number, c, capital_id)
    cadena = 'Draoumculiasis' + params + 'LandCrocodile' + url + 'Bevar-Asp'
    cadenau = cadena.encode('utf8')
    m = hashlib.sha1(cadenau)
    xs3 = m.hexdigest()
    headers = {
        'Host': realm,
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Content-Length': len(params),
        'Origin': 'http://castlemania-production.s3.amazonaws.com',
        'x-s3-aws': xs3,
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
        'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
        'DNT': 1,
        'Cookie': cookie }
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(realm, 80)
    conn.request('POST', url, params, headers)
    print('\nReleasing remaining: ', name)
    print('\nNumber of BATCHES done: ', built)
    print('***********************\nItems used:')
    print('===========')
    if testro != 0:
        print('Dark Testronius Powder: ', testro * built)
    if deluxe != 0:
        print('Dark Testronius Deluxe: ', deluxe * built)
    if infu != 0:
        print('Dark Testronius Infusion: ', infu * built)
    if jump != 0:
        print('Jump: ', jump * built)
    if leap != 0:
        print('Leap: ', leap * built)
    if bounce != 0:
        print('Bounce: ', bounce * built)
    if bore != 0:
        print('Bore: ', bore * built)
    if bolt != 0:
        print('Bolt: ', boltbr)
    if blast != 0:
        print('Blast: ', blast * built)
    if blitz != 0:
        print('Blitz: ', blitz * built)
    if build > 1 and build != built:
        print('\nWaiting for generals...')
        time.sleep(10)
    time.sleep(Duration)

totalpower = number * built * power
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print(79 * '=')
print('\nElapsed time: {0}'.format(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(elapsed_time))))
print('\n\nRevived {0} of {1} in total power of {2}'.format(format(number * built, ',d'), name, format(totalpower, ',d')))
print('\nReviving completed!!\n')
print(79 * '=')
input('Press Enter to Exit...')
```